# Directories under a path in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm using UKKQueue to keep an eye on changes to files in a directory. But sometimes there are more directories below the main one and it will not pick up changes to files made in those folders. Therefore I would like to also register those paths to be watched. I can't however get a folder list easily. I can get a list of EVERYTHING using...

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/Users/rob5408/Documents" error:&error];
```

...but how can I sift this further to get just directories? I looked at...

```
- (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path isDirectory:(BOOL *)isDirectory;
```

...but it seems tedious and the boolean pointer really threw me off. Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason you're not using FSEvents?

Comment: Honestly, each approach seems to have people that suggest another approach. I know I looked FSEvents before UKKQueue and wherever I was reading had pointed over to UKKQueue. Will FSEvents watch a whole directory tree worth of changes without any extra coding?

Comment: Actually,Now that I look back at it, it was the FSEvents wrapper SCEvents' author that praised the work done by UKKQueue. But maybe I should look SCEvents again.

Comment: That's what it's for: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/FSEvents_h I wouldn't say “without any extra coding”, but you don't need to handle subtrees, as FSEvents will tell you specifically which directories things happened in.

Comment: Actually I did try FSEvents before UKKQueue but it only would notify me of directory changes and not if files within the directories had been altered. Is there a way to get FSEvents to watch files?

Comment: Nope. If you need to watch individual files, that would be an answer to my first comment. ☺

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...but how can I sift this further to get just directories? I looked at...
>
> ```
> - (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path isDirectory:(BOOL *)isDirectory;
> ```
>
> ...but it seems tedious and the boolean pointer really threw me off.

A little tedious, but not too hard to use:

```
BOOL isDir;
if ([mgr fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir) {
     //It's a directory
}
```

You could always make a function (or a category on NSFileManager, as long as you name-tag the method selector appropriately) to wrap this method:

```
if (R5408_ObjectAtPathIsDirectory(path)) {
     //It's a directory
}
```

Note that if it *isn't* a directory, that doesn't mean it's a regular file; one other likely possibility (there are other possibilities) is that it's a symbolic link. Conversely, an alias will appear to be a regular file, but you may be more interested in the original than the alias.